# How to handle IKEv1 and IKEv2 diffie-hellman shared secret bits length not multiple of 8 in ACVP

Tags: diffie-hellman

Hi I found this question which I am currently struggling with.
[How to handle IKEv1 and IKEv2 diffie-hellman shared secret bits length not multiple of 8?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/81483/how-to-handle-ikev1-and-ikev2-diffie-hellman-shared-secret-bits-length-not-multi)

In ACVP, the input diffe-hellman shared secret bits isn't multiple of 8, for example, 521 in bits.
The given gxy is
9E50F9E86DAF773F657F5F32BA4C84E707284843F422A74DFC6877D236020F86B115230C3BA57A680AED1AF2F0CE59CBB3C5755D80EFCCC1DD350DE79781AC807180.
tried this input and also >> 7, none of them is correct.

Answer (score 0):

> The given gxy is 9E50F9E86DAF773F657F5F32BA4C84E707284843F422A74DFC6877D236020F86B115230C3BA57A680AED1AF2F0CE59CBB3C5755D80EFCCC1DD350DE79781AC807180. tried this input and also >> 7, none of them is correct.

That value is suspicious; it is larger than $2^{521}-1$, which is the largest value a coordinate on the curve P-521 can be.

Are you sure that is the correct value?

Comment: https://pages.nist.gov/ACVP/draft-celi-acvp-kdf-ikev1.html. In my demo files, the given dhlen is 521, the given gxy is 66 bytes, but most significant 7 bits are not 0.  there must be some way to convert this given inpug gxy. I tried shift, cutoff, none of them are correct.